# Is there a way to set an offset to a range-based for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, foreach

Suppose that these classes have an inner array of AnotherObjectClass type that can be accessed through a function called GetAnotherObjectClassTerms.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main() {

    // Suppose a default constructor that assigns values to the arrays
    AnObjectClass obj1;
    AnObjectClass obj2;

    for (AnotherObjectClass term1 : obj1.GetAnotherObjectClassTerms) {
        for (AnotherObejctClass term2 : obj2.GetAnotherObjectClassTerms) {
            if (term1 > term2) {
                std::cout << "Term 1 is greater than term 2" << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Term 1 is not greater than term 2" << std::endl;
                // OFFSET THIS INNER LOOP so it doesn't iterate through all the items again.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can do this in a normal for loop by creating a variable that holds that last index, so that when it starts iterating, it starts from that specific position.

The following code is to show my problem using a traditional for-loop as requested.

```
for (unsigned short i = 0, temp = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (unsigned short j = temp; j < 3; j++) {
        // This traditional for-loop iterates through a different range
        // whenever the 'temp' value is increased

        if (j > i) {
            std::cout << j << " > " << i << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << j << " <= " << i << std::endl;
            temp++;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the code above would be:

`Output #1: 0 <= 0`

`Output #2: 1 > 0`

`Output #3: 2 > 0`

`Output #4: 1 <= 1`

`Output #5: 2 > 1`

`Output #6: 2 <= 2`

As you can see, the inner loop doesn't iterate from the "beginning" whenever the variable temp is incremented.

So my question is: can this be done in a range-based for loop? If so, how this offset can be applied to a range-base for loop? Or, should I completely avoid this and go with a normal for-loop?

The real problem that I'm having is that *I need the inner loop to start by an offset by +1 when the break statements is reached*.

**Take into account that the range-based for is looping through the elements of an array.**

Comment: In C++17, there is a structured binding declaration.    Before C++17, you could provide a helper class, which wraps an instance of your class and provides its own tailored `begin()`, `end()` and other member functions that behave as you need - for one-off cases where you need to operate over part of a range, it is probably easier to use a "normal" for-loop.

Comment: Yes to your question, but I have no idea what your code is supposed to do.  There is no inner loop reasonable located where that comment is.  Snd I cannot parse the italic text in your question.  Regardless, you appear to need something like [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL).

Comment: @peter how would structured binding help here?

Comment: @Yakk my code is supposed to loop through an array of a user-defined object type. In my case, I have two of these objects with those inner arrays.

If you want a more specific explanation of what I'm coding, the objects are actually polynomials, and the arrays consist of the terms of the polynomials. I need to sum these two polynomials, but you can't sum terms in a polynomial with different degrees. The code I'm doing uses this concatenated ranged-for based loop to iterate through the terms of the polynomials (stored in arrays) in order to sum them correctly.

Comment: @Peter I had never heard of it, I'm going to search about it. How would you implement it?

Comment: Show also traditional loop code that shows exactly what you want to do… It is not clear enough from your actual question.

Comment: @Phil1970 Thanks for the feedback. I just added the code example in a traditional for-loop and added its corresponding output to clarify my question.

Comment: In your sample, every time you write `<=` in your output, `i` is equal to `j`. So it seems a bit suspicious. **If you have to do it only once, I would use regular `for` loops with iterators.** Otherwise, if I would need nested loops often, then I might consider writing a class that would return all desired pairs in a single loop.

Comment: @Phil1970 Well, it is true that i = j when the output of <= happens. It's just an example of how the temp serves as an offset in the inner loop, which is my problem when using the ranged-based for loop. I will try to implement the return for the desired pairs as you have suggested.

Also, what do you mean by doing it only once?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Boost, you can use [`boost::adaptors::sliced`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/sliced.html) to get a slice of your range. The following is a complete example:

```
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/sliced.hpp>

int main() {
    int a[] = {0,1,2}, b[] = {0,1,2};

    std::size_t off = 0;
    for (int term1 : a) {
        for (int term2 : b | boost::adaptors::sliced(off, std::size(b))) {
                                                          // ^^^^^^^^^ C++17 feature
            if (term1 > term2) {
                std::cout << "Term 1 is greater than term 2" << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Term 1 is not greater than term 2" << std::endl;
                ++off;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Term 1 is not greater than term 2
Term 1 is not greater than term 2
Term 1 is not greater than term 2
```

You can also implement a simple class, say `Offset`. When combined with a range, it returns a proxy class with `begin()` and `end()` member functions (so that it is able to behave like a range), say `View`, which represents the offseted range.

Example:

```
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

struct Offset {
    std::size_t _offset;
};

constexpr Offset offset(std::size_t s)
{
    return {s};
}

template <typename Iterator>
struct View {
    constexpr Iterator begin() const {return _begin;}
    constexpr Iterator end() const {return _end;}
    Iterator _begin;
    Iterator _end;
};

// Combine a range with an Offset using operator| like boost::adaptors::sliced
template <typename Range>
auto operator |(Range &&range, const Offset &offset) 
    -> View<decltype(std::begin(std::forward<Range>(range)))> 
{
    return {
        std::begin(std::forward<Range>(range)) + offset._offset, 
        std::end(std::forward<Range>(range))
    };
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {0,1,2}, b[] = {0,1,2};

    std::size_t off = 0;
    for (int term1 : a) {
        for (int term2 : b | offset(off)) {
            if (term1 > term2) {
                std::cout << "Term 1 is greater than term 2" << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Term 1 is not greater than term 2" << std::endl;
                ++off;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```